# java.lang.NullPointerException with XmlReader in libgdx

Tags: libgdx, xmlreader

this is my first time using xml and I have this problem:
here's the xml file :

```
<file>

<extension>.png</extension>

<animated>false</animated>

</file>
```

and here is the code I use to read the animated block :

```
isAnimated = Boolean.parseBoolean(xmlTextureFile.getChildByName("file").get("animated"));
```

and when I execute the program it gives the java.lang.NullPointerException error

Comment: Can you please add a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is the xmlTextureFile? How do you create this Object? There are 2 possibilities: xmlTextureFile is `null` or `getChildByName("file")` returns `null`. Please show some more code, or we cannot help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer,

xmlTextureFile is an Element and when you parse a file the first element used to parse is the fisrt tag (file here).

therefore here I only need to do

```
isAnimated = Boolean.parseBoolean(xmlTextureFile.get("animated"));
```